# Is this conversion valid in C

Tags: c, language-lawyer, implicit-conversion, void-pointers

As ***direct*** conversion to `void **` of other types is not valid is this conversion valid in C?

```
void swapValues(void **av, void **bv, size_t size)  
{  
    int *a = *av;
    int *b = *bv;
    char array[size];  
    memcpy(array, a, size);  
    memcpy(a, b, size);  
    memcpy(b, array, size);  
}  

int main()  
{  
    int i = 3;  
    int j = 5;  
    int *x = &i;
    int *y = &j;
    void *p = &i;  
    void *q = &j;  

    //this is invalid
    swapValues(&x, &y, sizeof(i));  

    //is this valid
    swapValues(&p, &q, sizeof(i));  
}
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/q/8166502/11683?

Comment: What conversion are you referring to? It seems that `void**` types are only initialized on function call and dereferenced within function.

Comment: @user694733 Series of conversions

Comment: @user694733 Because it shows proper ways of doing what is being done here, irrespective to the [exact method](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/66377/147640) shown here? There doesn't seem to be a need to use `void**` to begin with.

Comment: What problem do you see? What compiler/version do you use?

Comment: It's legal. Which conversion do you suspect isn't legal?

Comment: @GSerg The question is not "How to swap values** only about the language itself. The function is only an example.

Comment: @fukanchik this is a question about the standard, so compiler/version isn't relevant unless by "version" you mean "edition of the standard".

Comment: @PaulHankin any support in C standard? I am no looking for the opinion

Comment: I mean, one version converts `int**` to `void**`, while the other doesn't. So the later version has less wrong with it.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/q/75717720/11683?

Comment: You convert `int*` to `void*`, then take the address of the `void*` value. Later you dereference the `void**` to get a `void*`, then convert it back to `int*`. All these steps are individually obviously valid, so any problem would have to be some sort of special rule (like strict aliasing) that makes the code illegal. Without making the question specific about something in the standard (eg: "does this code violate strict aliasing") it's hard to give a proof that it's valid because it's hard to show that something doesn't exist. Maybe others can find a way...

Comment: @GSerg that's not the same -- the question you like to is asking whether it's valid to convert a `void**` into a `void*` and back, whereas this code takes the address of a `void*` to get a `void**`.

Comment: Oops - Sorry, I'm getting muddled up, here.

Comment: why don't you just change the arguments to void*? why do you need the extra layer of pointers?

Comment: @user253751 you do not understand the question.

Comment: @0___________ I don't understand which conversion you are asking about. It's valid to write `&p` to get the address of `p` - just like any other variable. Why would that not be valid?

Comment: (General moan at the world.) I wish there were a standard library function for swapping blocks of memory. It's easy to write one that can swap memory blocks a byte at a time, but it would be hoped that a standard library function would make use of what would otherwise be undefined behavior (if it weren't part of the standard library) to optimize the operation and still use O(1) additional storage.

Comment: Interesting DV-es. Any explanation

Answer (score 1):

These conversions of argument expressions

```
swapValues(&p, &q, sizeof(i));
```

to corresponding function parameters

```
void swapValues(void **av, void **bv, size_t size)
```

are correct. The first two argument expressions have the type `void **` and the corresponding function parameters have the same type `void **`.

Within the function in these declarations

```
int *a = *av;
int *b = *bv;
```

the expressions `*av` and `*bv` having the type `void *` may be used as initializers for the pointers `a` and `b` of the type `int *` without explicit casting because (the C Standard)

> 1 A pointer to void may be converted to or from a pointer to any
> object type. A pointer to any object type may be converted to a
> pointer to void and back again; the result shall compare equal to the
> original pointer.

Actually these declarations

```
int *a = *av;
int *b = *bv;
```

are redundant.

You could just write without them

```
char array[size];  
memcpy(array, *av, size);  
memcpy(*av, *bv, size);  
memcpy(*bv, array, size);
```